# Radio Button Navigation issue in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have Loaded 3 radio button inside the Grid panel using the column definition(each with in a specific column) On this time i have noticed that the arrow key navigation is not properly Working. But the Tab and shift+tab Navigation are working as per the expectations. That the same is working fine while loading the radio button inside the stack panel. After the various inspection i have noticed that the issue occurs while Using Horizontal alignment property of the Radio button as Left. It give the same odd behavior for all the option except stretch.Can anyone describe how to resolve this issue.

I have tried applying of Group Name to the Radio Button also

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <RadioButton Content="Automatic" Grid.Column="1" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedSizeType, Converter={StaticResource EnumBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Apple}"/>
                            <RadioButton Content="Manual" Grid.Column="3" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedSizeType, Converter={StaticResource EnumBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mango}"/>
                            <RadioButton Content="Customizable" Grid.Column="5" x:Name="Customizable" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedSizeType, Converter={StaticResource EnumBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Carrot}"/>
                        </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? The arrow keys should work by default. The grouped buttons must have focus.

Comment: @BionicCode I have updated the code

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. There must be something else involved beyond what you're shown in your question.

Comment: Its one of the part of my user control.. Similar that i have some set of TextBox, DataGrid in may design. On the design some Radio Button are loaded inside the stack panel, in this case Navigation all are working fine. That the side is only with Grid

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the attached property [`KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation?view=netframework-4.8) on the grouping container element to force a certain navigation behavior according to it's [`KeyboardNavigationMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode?view=netframework-4.8#fields) value.

The following example sets `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` to `KeyboardNavigationMode.Local` on the containing `Grid`:

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local" >
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <RadioButton Content="Automatic" Grid.Column="1" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  <RadioButton Content="Manual" Grid.Column="3" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  <RadioButton Content="Customizable" Grid.Column="5" x:Name="Customizable" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```